# Meteor: accounts-facebook with facebookConnectPlugin

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, facebook-login

I'm using the accounts-password and accounts-facebook packages so i can be able to use Meteor.user().

The problem is that on my mobile app i want to be able to use facebook to login. Also, i'm using https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin to be able to use native facebook login on android.

When i use facebookConnectPlugin, the login method doesn't set the Meteor.user() variable, so i can't use it anymore.

Here's my question, is there a way i can use facebook login on android with the accounts-facebook package? Or, is there a way i can set the Meteor.user() after facebookConnectPlugin successfully connects?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is the accounts-facebook package not working on mobile?

Comment: Yes it's working but it's using the web version of facebook not the facebook app. So there's a message saying that the user should use the app. Also, if the user is already logged in the facebook app, it doesn't loggin your app automatically.